# Возраст из типа date

Tags: php, дата

```
$qr = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT date FROM users WHERE id=13 ");
    $date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr);
```

Вот массив `date`, как мне из этого типа - пример (`1990-05-17`) отобразить возраст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = '1990-01-01';
$age = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $date)
     ->diff(new DateTime('now'))
     ->y;

echo $age;
```

Где:

`createFromFormat` - Создает и возвращает экземпляр класса DateTime, соответствующий заданному формату 
http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php

`diff` (аналог `date_diff` в процедурном стиле) -  Возвращает разницу между двумя DateTime объектами (относится к [DateTimeInterface](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetimeinterface.php))

`y` - как уже понятно - возвращает именно разницу в годах.

Answer (score 0):

если запросом из базы то можно и вот таким запросиком

CREATE FUNCTION `get_age` (
  `date` DATE,
  `current_time` DATETIME
) RETURNS INT(11) UNSIGNED COMMENT 'Calculates the age from the date of birth' DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER
RETURN ((YEAR(current_time) - YEAR(date )) - ((DATE_FORMAT(current_time, '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(date , '00-%m-%d'))));

SELECT get_age(date, NOW()) AS age FROM users WHERE id=13

или на пхп вот так

```
$date = '1990-05-17';
$d = explode('-',$date);
getAge($d[0], $d[1], $d[2]);

function getAge($y, $m, $d) {
if($m > date('m') || $m == date('m') && $d > date('d'))
  return (date('Y') - $y - 1);
else
  return (date('Y') - $y);
}
```

Comment: В MySQL нет встроенной функции get_age

Comment: добавил, спасибо за то что обратили мое внимание на неполный ответ

Comment: И зачем так сложно, функцию еще создавать, не проще `select TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, date, CURDATE())` ?

Comment: возьму себе на заметку, надо попробовать ваш метод